# My recursion solution does not work but DP solution works and I don't know why

Tags: java, recursion, dynamic-programming, fibonacci

I am working on finding a **modified version** of nth fibonacci number using recursion. a1 = 0, a2 = 1, a3 = a1 + a2^2, a4 = a2 + a3^2...and so on

```
fib(0, 1, n);
public static void fib(BigInteger t1, BigInteger t2, int n) {
    if (n == 3) {
        System.out.println(t1.add(t2.multiply(t2)));
    } else {
        fib(t2.multiply(t2), t1.add(t2.multiply(t2)), n - 1);
    }
}
```

The answer works for smaller numbers. fib(0, 1, 5) returns 5. But, fib(6) returns 29 instead of 27

However, my DP solution below outputs correct values;

```
public static void fib(BigInteger t1, BigInteger t2, int n) {
    BigInteger[] bi = new BigInteger[n];
    bi[0] = t1;
    bi[1] = t2;
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        bi[i] = bi[i-2].add(bi[i-1].multiply(bi[i-1]));
    }
    System.out.println(bi[n-1]);
}
```

fib(0, 1, 5) returns 5 and fib(6) outputs 27.
I cannot seem to figure out why this is the case.

Comment: Please supply a series of results, so we can see where the two diverge.

Comment: The recursive method is wrong because you are not returning anything

Comment: It doesn't need to return anything; as in the DP solution, the only result is the printed output.

Comment: This is not a Fibonacci number. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number

Comment: I noted "modified version" in my question.

Comment: @JeanieJ, please remember to "accept" an answer, so that SO can properly retire the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recursive solution doesn't match the recurrence description you give.  Your call passes down two arguments:

```
t2^2
t1 + t2^2
```

That first one should not be squared.

```
fib(t2, t1.add(t2.multiply(t2)), n - 1);
```

That done, I get the following results for values 3 through 10:

```
1
2
5
27
734
538783
290287121823
84266613096281243382112
```

Answer (score 0):

My apologies.. I just saw a bug on my recursive call. It should have been

```
fib(t2, t1.add(t2.multiply(t2)), n - 1);
```

instead of

```
fib(t2.multiply(t2), t1.add(t2.multiply(t2)), n - 1);
```

Comment: ... which is just what I posted a few minutes before.  :-)